# How to create regex for the expression starts with and ends with curly braces?

Tags: python, regex

I want to find a string in a text file which starts with `'{"ABC":'` and ends with `'}'`.

So far I have tried following:

```
re.findall('^{\"ABC(.)*$}', text_string, re.MULTILINE)
```

But it's not working as expected.

Comment: try `'^\{"ABC(.*)\}$'` instead. But I suspect you're trying to parse JSON with regexes. There are better ways.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually I am trying to parse a text file in which one of the lines is a JSON that I want.

Comment: try this: `{"ABC":(.*)}`

Comment: Thanks this worked. But I am not getting ABC in the output now.

Comment: you need 2 groups then: `{("ABC"):(.*)}`

Comment: can you share some sample input?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capture the whole string:

```
re.findall('({"ABC":.*})', text_string, re.MULTILINE)
```

If you want to capture just the contents:

```
re.findall('{"ABC":(.*)}', text_string, re.MULTILINE)
```

Of course, this can be useful to extract JSON-like structures from plain text data, but do not use regex for parsing any sort of structured/multi-level data - use a parser created for it, like the built-in module `json` for JSON.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - true that, an old habit from `sed` ;)

Comment: answer works but I'm convinced that this isn't the way to go. The way to go would be `json` parsing (or `ast.literal_eval`).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - judging by his comment above - he's trying to extract JSON from the rest of a text in which case regex is a valid option. I'll add a disclaimer, tho.

Comment: chaining `json.loads` to `re.findall` would be a good option too.